# Do I need a Japanese visa?

Tags: visas, transit, japan

I'm travelling to San Francisco (SFO) with family this May. My first flight is with JAL to Narita. After a 12hr layover, the next flight is from Haneda to San Francisco. Similar routing on the way back a few weeks later (SFO-HND / NRT - ? ). Do I need a visa for Japan and if yes, what kind?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: @Traveller He is extremely likely to be Indian.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the presumption you hold a passport issued by India (I Googled your name). I entered your data into Timatic which the airline will also use (and deny boarding if you don't have the necessary documentation). It shows you need a visa. Checking visa types, the [transit visa](https://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html) will be enough as it is valid for 15 days maximum.

[image]